# Python to group elements in specified column

Tags: python, collections, count

I would like to count the number of all unique elements in a 3rd column and would like some insight on the most pythonic way to achieve this result.

My input data is as follows:

```
act by+n+n-a-bas    act 0.04809825
act by+n+n-a-bas    art 0.01603275
act by+n+n-a-bas    evt 0.01603275
act nmod+ns-the-j+n-a   art 11.6016481452
act nmod+ns-the-j+n-a   pro 1.40733988889
act nmod+ns-the-j+n-a   pos 0.757101266667
act nmod+ns-the-j+n-a   pho 1.7562449
```

My desired result is the following:

```
act act 1
act art 2
act evt 1
act pro 1
act pos 1
act pho 1
```

In which I sum the number of unique elements for each different value in Col3. For instance, would the `collections()` make sense here, although the value in Col1 is always the same? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Counter` like this

```
from collections import Counter
with open("Input.txt") as inFile:
    print Counter([" ".join(line.split()[::2]) for line in inFile])
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'act art': 2, 'act pho': 1, 'act act': 1, 'act pro': 1, 'act evt': 1,
'act pos': 1})
```